# RSA encryption using blocks

Tags: java, encryption, block, rsa

I am trying to implement RSA encryption using blocks to cut down the run time of decrypting with large bits lengths. The way my program is now, it works but reads individual characters and decrpyts them. So as you might imagine, the run time for large bit lengths is long.

Is there a way to easily implement decryption using blocks so that it works faster for these large bit lengths. Examples of code with an implementation would be nice if it is easy and feasible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it appears that you're using the following encryption scheme:

```
for i=0 to length(input):
    output(RSA_encrypt(key, input[i]))
```

This is not a secure encryption scheme.  You appear to be asking for a way to do something similar to

```
for i=0 to blocks(input):
    output(RSA_encrypt(key, block(i, input)))
```

That is likewise not secure.  Secure RSA-based encryption schemes generally involve encrypting a unique session key with RSA then encrypting the message using a symmetric cipher such as AES.  For instance, see [RSAES-OAEP](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf).  Don't try implementing it yourself, because you're likely to get it wrong.  Instead, use a reputable cryptographic library.

Always remember the Rules of Crypto:

1. Never design your own crypto.
2. Never implement your own crypto.
3. Anyone can design crypto that they can't break themselves.

Comment: +1 for `Never design your own crypto` and `Never implement your own crypto`. Thank you.